# How prove this $\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{b}\ge |(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)|+a+b+c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

let $a,b,c$ are positive numbers,and  such $abc\le 1$,prove that
$$\dfrac{a}{c}+\dfrac{b}{a}+\dfrac{c}{b}\ge |(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)|+a+b+c$$

Comment: I'm just wondering ... what have you attempted?

Comment: becasuse  This problem is very interesting, and I think this problem have many methods,Thank you

Comment: why someone think this problem is not usefull?

Comment: I hope you interesting the inequality,Please consider sometime then you vote!!!!

Comment: and I like inequality, and especially like nice methods.

Comment: It's not that "the question is useful/interesting" that matters, it's your attempt to solve the question; you're not showing any motivation on this problem (and most of your previous questions)

Comment: I have try solve this problem,But I falied,I think I ask all question is consider sometime,and most of are very interesting and very hard.I think some of like my question,

Comment: It's better for you to post what you have tried, even you have failed to solve the problem

Comment: For example, a little rearrangement and AM-GM inequality gives me this: $a/c + b/a + c/b - (a+b+c) \geq 3((1-a)(1-b)(1-c))^{1/3}$. Have you tried this approach? Could you proceed further? It might not lead to the ultimate solution, but you must mention some attempt!

Comment: At the very least (and for the umpteenth time), please give the source for the problems you post.

Comment: @DannyCheuk There's a discussion about this is meta that you might want to look at. Someone people just like posting nice questions, and there's nothing wrong with posting nice questions without showing work. See the meta for more.

Comment: And some of us think there is something wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

case 1:
For case $a<1,b<1,c<1$, it is trivial the inequality work(Sudeep's comments)

case 2:
now we prove when one of $a,b,c$ equals $1$,the inequality also works.

WLOG,Let $c=1$, the inequality $\iff b^2+a \ge ab^2+ab$, let $ab=k \le 1 \iff b^3-kb^2-kb+k \ge0 \iff b^3(1-k)+k(b-1)^2(b+1)\ge0$

so the "=" will hold when $k=1,b=1 \implies a=b=c=1$

we will prove the case $abc=1$ first:

there are two cases:

case 3: two of them $\ge 1$  , the inequality $\iff  \dfrac{a}{c}+\dfrac{b}{a}+\dfrac{c}{b}\ge ab+bc+ac \iff a^3b^3-a^2b^3+b^3-b^2-ab+1\ge 0 \iff $

$b^3(a-1)^2(a+1)+(b^2-1)(a-1) \ge 0$ when $a,b$ both $\ge 1 $
$b(ab-1)^2(ab+1)+b^2(1-b)(a^2-1) \ge 0 $ when one of $a,b \ge1$ and another $\le1$

case 4: one of them $\ge1$, the other two $\le1$ ,the inequality $\iff  \dfrac{a}{c}+\dfrac{b}{a}+\dfrac{c}{b}\ge 2(a+b+c)-(ab+bc+ac) \iff a^3b^3+a^2b^3+b^3+b^2+1-2ab^3-2a^2b^2-2b \ge0 \iff (b-1)^2+ab(ab-1)^2+b^3(a-1)^2 \ge 0$

now we discuss $a'b'c'<1$ cases:

let $a'b'c'=k^3,a'=ka,b'=kb,c'=kc,abc=1$, we only consider RHS becasue LHS will be same.

denote $H$ for $a,b,c ,H'$ for $a',b',c'$,

if $H'$ in case 3,then $H$ will be in case 3 also:

$H-H'=(ab+bc+ac)(1-k^2)>0$

if both $H'$ and $H $ in case 4:

$H-H'=2(1-k)(a+b+c)-(1-k^2)(ab+bc+ac)+1-k^3$, let $c \ge 1 \iff $

$2(1-k)(a^2b+b^2a+1)-(1-k^2)(a^2b^2+a+b)+(1-k^3)ab =(1-k)((2ab-(1+k))(a+b)+2)+(1-k)(1+k)(ab-a^2b^2)+(1-k)k^2ab \ge 0 \implies H \ge H'$

if $H'$ in case 4, but $H$ in case 3, then there is always one case that $a=ka'>1$ suppose $c \ge 1, a\ge b$ we can chose $k_2=\dfrac{1}{a'}$,then $a=1,b\le1, c\ge 1$ which make $H$ still in case 4. and $H$ now is belong to case 2.So the inequality is also true.

QED.